# Is it possible to implement multiple test runners in pyunitest? while only running the test suite once

Tags: python, python-3.x, teamcity, python-unittest, runner

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if is_running_under_teamcity():
        runner = TeamcityTestRunner()
    else:
        runner =  HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
                stream=outfile,
                title='Test Report',
                description='This is an example.'
                )
    unittest.main(testRunner=runner)
```

I am currently running some tests using unittest module in python this is my current code above. I am deploying this test setup on Teamcity, the first module allows me to convert the output into teamcity-messages and the second creates a html report of the results. Is there a way I can run both of these runners while only running one set of tests? The only option I can see at the minuete is to either try and combine both these modules into a hybrid or using another testing module that Teamcity supports. However I would like to keep the dependancies as low as possible

Any ideas would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas would be great :)

Looks like you'll have to handroll it, looking at the code TeamcityTestRunner is a pretty simple extension of the standard TextTestRunner, however HTMLTestRunner is a way more complex beast.

Sadly this is one area of the stdlib which is really badly architected: one could expect the *test runner* to be concerned solely with discovering and running tests, however it's also tasked with part of the *test reporting* rather than have an entirely separate test reporter (this test reporting is furthermore a split responsability with the test result, which shouldn't be part of that one's job description either).

Frankly if you don't have any further customisation **I'd suggest just using `pytest` as your test runner** instead of unittest with a custom runner:

- it should be able to run unittest tests fine
- IME it has better separation of concerns and pluggability so having multiple reporters / formatters should work out of the box

  - pytest-html certainly has no issue generating its reports without affecting the normal text output
  - according to the readme teamcity gets automatically enabled and used for pytest
  - so I'd assume generating html reports during your teamcity builds would work fine (to test)
- and you can eventually migrate to using pytest tests (which are so much better it's not even funny)

Comment: I tried py-test, however as part of my tests I am running sub processes and when these run with py-test it always seems to fail ? is it something pytest supports? if so i will continue with that!

Comment: @charlie I don't know. I can't say that I've ever had any issue creating / running subprocesses in pytest (even using xdist), so it might depend on what you're doing specifically.

Comment: ok perfect i will carry on integrating pytest instead to save a handrolled headache! Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: out of interest this is the error im getting if you would like to take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281122/subprocesses-not-running-with-pytest-error-processing-test